# Can I wrap text around images only on paragraphs that do not contain any actual text without javascript?

Tags: html, css

I have something similar to the following html:

```
<p>
    <a><img src="/path/to/image.gif"></a>
    Plenty of text here.....
</p>
<p>
    <a><img src="/path/to/another/image.gif"></a>
</p>
<p>
    Plenty of text here.....
</p>
```

What I would like to wrap the text around the image that has text adjacent to it and center the image that has no text adjacent to it.

How can I do that using *only* css?

This html is on an incoming RSS feed that I do not have control over. I can change the content once it comes in (via a configurable style sheet).

I am also not able to add any ids or classes, so I must be able to select the items with `p`, `a`, `img`, and any meta classes.

Comment: I do not think it is possible. Have been doing some research, with current HTML it seems impossible. If you chance the HTML `:empty` or `element+element` might be useful

Comment: Is there some sort of meta class for text? I didn't see one but I could possibly do something like `img + :text`?

Comment: Dont think there's something like that. Try watching in the w3schools selectors reference for a clear overview.